# Is there a way to protect particle board cabinets from moisture/water?

Tags: wood, wood-finishing, particle-board

I've been researching cabinet options and one of the cons of particle board or MDF cabinets is that they don't respond well to moisture.

So, is there a way for me to protect, finish PB or MDF cabinets so that I can minimize moisture damage?

I would really only have to do this to the cabinets that are close to moisture sources...such as by the sink, and by the stove.

**UPDATE**
We're considering IKEA cabinets.

Comment: You haven't told us what sort of finish they have now. Cheap paper veneer? Actual wood? Paint?

Comment: Many of the cabinets are unfinished on the inside. Painting the wood with a good sealer on the inside of the sink and dish washer can help extend the life. These are the 2 areas the cabinets tend to get damp and fall apart. Other than a broken pipe where water swelled all the cabinet bases I have not had troubles next to the stove. A bad flood can even damage plywood if not cleaned and dried quickly.

Comment: Most people opt for a _glossy paint_ to protect it from minor splashes. You can paint or varnish it, or cover it with plastic or something.
Here's a good link that talks about various pros and cons regarding treatments: http://120studio.com/tech/workbench-finishes.htm
A dehumidifier is the answer to moisture/humidity control.